# Simple MySQL code not inserting data into database?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working at this for hours, and can't seem to get these few lines of code to work. This is the first time I've worked with MySQL, so bear with me.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","usernamewitheld","passwordwithheld");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("splashpage");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'email' ('emailaddress') VALUES ('$_POST[email]');", $con);
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

The code executes without any errors from apache, but the database remains unaffected. Any ideas?

EDIT: Table structure is as follows:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
emailaddress    text    NO  MUL NULL     
timesubmitted   timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: could  you please post table structure as well ?

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove semi colon, use bacticks instead of single quotes in query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `email` (`emailaddress`) VALUES ('$_POST[email]')", $con)
or     
die(mysql_error());
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

use backtick `` ` `` here around column name not `'`

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'email' ('emailaddress') VALUES ('$_POST[email]');", $con);
```

should be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `email` (`emailaddress`) VALUES ('$_POST[email]')", $con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
<?php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO email (emailaddress) VALUES ('".$_POST[email]."')", $con);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","usernamewitheld","passwordwithheld");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("splashpage",$con);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'email' ('emailaddress') VALUES ('$_POST[email]');", $con);
 echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```